Why does minimizing formal charge imply more stability?
I have been told resonance contributors with more formally charged atoms are energetically unfavorable (viz. Wikipedia). Why is this so? This link claims that minimization of formal charge carriers leads to an even distribution of electrons. So perhaps presence of formal charges creates a charge separation, leading to increase in the potential energy of the molecules?
Formal charges are just a number we assign to certain Lewis structures (for example, see this question). In the Lewis structure of the hydronium ion, the (formal) positive charge is assigned to the oxygen atom. But if oxidation states are compared, it oxygen has an OS of -2, implying it has a negative charge in some way.
My questions are:

Why should minimizing the number formal charge = V - N - B lead to
stability?
What is special about the formal charge in that it can calculate which structures are stable?


:/ Instead of telling not to break bonds for no good reason they give you some abstract equation.
